# Fabric js animateColor function not found error

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

**Fabric js animateColor function not found an error. my code for animate text color**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
var text = new fabric.Text('text', {
    left: 10,
    top: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 15,
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica Nue, Helvetica, Sans-Serif, Arial, Trebuchet MS'
    });

canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();

text.animateColor('#000000','#ffffff',100);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animateColor` is a utility and it is located in the `fabric.util` namespace. You can read more about it here: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.animateColor.

An example of animating text color using `fabric.util.animateColor`:

```js
const ANIMATION_DURATION = 1000;
const colors = ['red', 'aqua'];

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
const text = new fabric.Text('Animate Color', {
    fill: colors[0],
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica Nue'
});

canvas.add(text);

const swapColors = () => colors.push(colors.shift());
const toRgba = (val) => Array.isArray(val) 
  ? fabric.Color.fromSource(val).toRgba() 
  : new fabric.Color(val).toRgba();
const demoColorAnimation = () => {
  fabric.util.animateColor(
    colors[0], 
    colors[1], 
    ANIMATION_DURATION, 
    {
      onChange: (val) => {
        text.setColor(toRgba(val));

        canvas.renderAll();
      },
      onComplete: () => {
        swapColors();
        demoColorAnimation();
      }
    }
  );
};

demoColorAnimation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help I really appreciated.